# Proper Angularjs way to use JSON maintain RESTful urls

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, rest

I am building an Angularjs web application *by the books* I guess you could say. I am following the [John Papa Angular Styleguide](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide/blob/master/a1/README.md) and things have been going well so far. I now have a need to keep all of the RESTful host urls in some sort of configuration file in JSON format. These host endpoints change frequently depending on the client or change of AWS machines, so to keep all of the urls in one place could be beneficial for ease of change.

Currently in the javascript files in my application that deal with making the REST calls things are setup like this:

```
 function ModelViewService($http, $q, exception, logger) {
        var HOST = 'http://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.amazonaws.com';
        var MODULE = '/modelview/service/rest';
        ...
```

And then when a call is made to get some data for example it looks like this:

```
    function getGroups() {
        return $http.get(HOST + MODULE + '/group/retrieveAll')
            .then(success)
            .catch(fail);
        ...
```

I then have other files with different services and different HOSTs so I basically want to house JSON objects somewhere that look like:

```
{
    'modelviewservice': {
        'HOST':  'http://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.amazonaws.com',
        'MODULE': '/modelview/service/rest'
    },
    ... //other service
}
```

And then back in the javascript file do something like `$http.get(config.modelviewservice.host + config.modelviewservice.MODULE + '/group/retrieveAll')`.

I don't know the best way to achieve this and follow the angular style guide. I found something called `requre.js` that apparently would inject the `config.json` file into the javascript via something like `var config = require('config.json')('./config.json');` where the first `config.json` refers to the [config.json](https://www.npmjs.com/package/config.json) npm module, and the second `./config.json` refers to my local configuration JSON file. This seemed like an ok solution but since I couldn't get it to work it had me second guessing if there was an easier or more proper way to do this.

Comment: How about creating an angular constant?

Comment: Care to elaborate on how/where that would be created? It's important for all of the REST urls to be in the same file, and the different files that need them to be able to access the file that houses the urls.

Comment: Btw `retrieveAll` is not RESTful at all, as a resource name : P

Comment: How so? I'm willing to learn the proper way. If I need to get all of something is there correct verbiage to use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, this is how I do it to make my endpoints organize. Add constant to main module of the application .

```
(function() {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('apiConstant', [])
        .constant('apiConstant', constant());

    function constant() {
        return {
            HOST: 'http://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.amazonaws.com',
            modules: {
                MODULE_1: '/modelview/service/rest',
                MODULE_2: '/modelview/factory/rest',
                MODULE_3: '/modelview/sample/rest'
            },
            endpoints: {
                GET_GROUPS: '/group/retrieveAll',
                GET_USERS: '/users/retrieveAll',
                POST_GROUP: '/group/add'
            }
        };
    }
})();
```

And then in your service

```
function ModelViewService($http, $q, exception, logger, apiConstant) {
        var HOST = apiConstant.HOST;
        var MODULE = apiConstant.modules.MODULE_1;
        ...


function getGroups() {
        return $http.get(HOST + MODULE + apiConstant.endpoints.GET_GROUPS)
            .then(success)
            .catch(fail);
        ...
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I will try and implement this to see if it works for me. What would the top js file be called? Whatever I want? And for the `ModelViewService.$inject = ['$http', '$q', 'exception', 'logger']` do I need to include the file name there, or include `'apiConstant'`?

Comment: Yep, whatever you want. You should also inject it like this `ModelViewService.$inject = ['$http', '$q', 'exception', 'logger', 'apiConstant']`

Comment: Also, you need to add to your module dependency. Or you can rename the `.module('apiConstant', [])` to your module. :)

Comment: Thanks, that last part was what was messing me up.